# how to get the format 2012-11-19T19:35:00.0000000-07:00 from NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a format 2012-11-19T19:35:00.0000000-07:00 how can I acheive this from NSDate?

```
 NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
 NSString *dateString =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
 NSLog(@"Date is: %@",dateString);
```

I get the NSLog as 2012-11-09T14:22:00+0530
But I want 2012-11-09T19:35:00.0000000-07:00

How can I get this out.Please help me out.

Comment: replied after one month :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya : Sorry yaar I was bc with some tasks!!! :)

Comment: I wonder why you are not Pavithra ? Arent you malyali ?

Comment: I am a bit of keralite :) was born in cochin :)

Comment: we should not use SO for chat, u can find my email id in my profile.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22496/discussion-between-pavitra-and-anoop-vaidya)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZZ"];
```

More on how to format dates with NSFormater [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.But this give me an output 2012-11-09T15:07:03.3750000+0530 but I want 2012-11-09T15:07:03.3750000+05:30.Can You please help me out?

Comment: But this gives me output as 2012-11-09T15:15:22.5620000GMT+05:30.I dont want GMT in between.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I think I need to parse it out.

Comment: Thanks,Got it  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];

Answer (score 1):

`NSDate` conforms to Unicode Technical Standard, you'll need to look into [Date_Format_Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) to find out the format you want,

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement, you can do this one. The result will be as

```
//Your desired : 2012-11-09T19:35:00.0000000-07:00 
//You will get : 2012-11-09T12:30:00.0000000+05:30

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZZ"];
```

Comment: Thanks,Got it  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];

Comment: Thxs Pavi, even I learnt somthing now from you. I hv updtd my ansr. And what i was going to suggest was this...

Comment: NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ"];
    
    NSDate *today = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"2012-11-09T19:35:00.0000000-07:00"];
    NSMutableString *dateString =[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]];
    NSLog(@"Date is: %@",dateString);//2012-11-09T12:30:00.0000000+0530
    
    [dateString insertString:@":" atIndex:[dateString length]-2];
    NSLog(@"Date is: %@",dateString);//2012-11-09T12:30:00.0000000+0530